# Inline SVG alignment in HTML

Tags: html, svg, alignment

I currently have problems aligning inline SVG correctly inside a bounding DIV, like in this example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; width: 100px; vertical-align:top;">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill: red;" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The SVG gets resized to match the the dimensions of the div, but I am not able to set any alignment for the SVG. Neither text-align nor vertical-align seem to work in Firefox 9, Chrome 18, IE 9 or Opera 11.61 . I just want to position the inline SVG at the upper left corner of the DIV.

Note that in my case the surrounding DIV has dynamic dimmension (%-values), so using absolute positioning does not work.

Anybody have any clue how to align the SVG in this case?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"` as an attribute on the svg element e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/fLWhu/

Comment: It displays in the top left for me. Try drawing a picture of what you want if that isn't it.

Comment: weird. did not worked. but as jsfiddle clearly shows - its working. // _changing my downvote to upvote_

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this... thank you :-)

Comment: The `preserveAspectRatio` property indeed helps align the contents of an SVG. It has many options though, see what works for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Answer (score 0):

Add `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` attribute to `<svg>` element
as per http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html.

Comment: Why would that position it in the upper left corner which is what the OP wanted?