# Vertically aligning SVG with other HTML elements

Tags: css, html

I need to align an SVG element in-line (to the right) of another element in a row/span, and cannot find the right formula.  Unless I'm doing something wrong, the answer to this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017204/inline-svg-alignment-in-html) fails when the SVG is not on the left.

Here's a [jsfiddle illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/J8sPs/). Grateful for assistance.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 100px; width: 200px; vertical-align:top;">
    <span height=100 float=left><p>text on left</p></span>
    <span height=100 float=right>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill: red;" />
        </svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Resolved it now! Please have a look at the answer and the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to get your spans next to each other here: http://jsfiddle.net/J8sPs/6/

Here is the final code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="flt"><p>text on left</p></span>
    <span class="frt">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
        </svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px; 
    width:  200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

span {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.flt {
    float: left;
}

.frt {
    float: right;
}

rect {
    fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works! But it is bizarre that the html assignment of rect colour only works via css in this model. I'm slightly concerned that the cause of this might lead other SVG attributes to fail.

Comment: That may not be the case. Having embedded styles in the HTML hinders my thinking and so I separated the two.

Comment: You're right it doesnn't I must've typo'd something. Thanks again for your help Chandranshu

Comment: You should get a cookie for this :-)

Comment: THANKS!  I was trying to hack up a quick checkbox for a jQuery pop-up div added dynamically and thought rather than HTML5 canvas drawing (which has no rounded rect function) I'd just make a rounded border and draw an X with svg but I couldn't figure out how to get the X to align with the top of the border; there was a gap. After adding the viewbox statement (instead of just width and height) it worked. (I didn't need the preserveAspectRatio attribute for this simple thing).  Saved me a lot of time!